# Advantage Database Server (10.1) in ASP.NET Web Forms App for User Management

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity, advantage-database-server

We are using Advantage Database Server (ADS) to store data that is being used by some dashboard components in an ASP.NET 4.5 Web Form application. My connection string is set up to connect to my ADS DB in order to generate the dashboard visualizations, and it works great. However, when trying to use the built in forms for authentication and authorization, I don't know how to get the data to store in ADS.

Normally it would create a localDb SQL-like database, and store the .mdf files in the App_Data folder. However, I am not using this default connection, but am instead connecting to my ADS DB. Is there a way to utilize the Identity functions, but use ADS to store the user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I discovered the answer is "no." MySQL (and also MariaDB) can be used to store the Identity user and role tables, but not ADS.